# Mysql COUNT subscribers for every route id

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

I have a MYSQL query problem and I'd like some help please.
I have 2 tables.

`subscriber: id, campaign_id`

`route: id, service_code, shortcode`

Let's say that: campaign_id = shortcode.

I want to execute a query that takes all the routes and counts the subscribers for each one of them.

I expect the output to be like:

`Route  | COUNT`

`44123  | 12`

`44566  | 48`

`44213  | 2`

`etc`

Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` the two tables, then use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`. Something like:

```
SELECT
  service_code, COUNT(COALESCE(s.id, 0)) AS `Count`
FROM route AS r 
LEFT JOIN Subscriber AS s ON r.shortcode = s.compaign_id
GROUP BY service_code
```

Comment: @HarrisGeo `COALESCE` will give 0 if there is any one that has no counts, instead of displaying nulls it displays 0

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
select r.service_code, count(*)
from route r join subscriber s on s.campaign_id = r.shortcode
group by r.service_code;
```

Comment: returns 1 in every count result